# Schema.org Website SearchAction

Tags: rich-snippets, structured-data

I want to include structured data into my website and I have a couple of questions regarding the WebSite SearchAction stuff. After [reading the docs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/sitelinks-searchbox) and looking at examples, it is not very clear to me if I do really have to implement any kind of page for that URL in case that is pasted into the browser?

Let's say I have `www.example.com` and I implement `www.example.com/search?q={query_string}`. At the moment the route `www.example.com/search?q=whatever` would return 404 therefore I don't know what "landing" page or response needs to be written.

Answer (score 1):

Your landing page would be the PHP (or other language) that graps the q=whatever and creates the search results page.

I believe you can use the Google programmable search API ...

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/creatingcse

... to build the page. For Google's API you need to have an adsence account. For the free unlimited usage they want to run ads and pay you money. If you don't want ads you need to pay for usage.

You have control over what sites are listed and can manually boost the pages you want first.

Google's API also gives you both a json interface (paid), to build your own search results page or a javascript built page.

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/implementingsearchbox

### Javascript search box for google's custom search API

```
<script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=YOUR_ENGINE_ID"></script>
<div class="gcse-searchbox-only" data-resultsUrl="YOUR_RESULTS_PAGE_URL"></div>
```

### Javascript results using Googles Custom Search API

```
<script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=YOUR_ENGINE_ID"></script>
<div class="gcse-searchresults-only"></div>
```